# Facebook App Review procedure for Page Public Content Access does not fit to server side script

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been tasked with continuing the development of an older PHP backend for a mobile app.

The PHP backend is supposed to request the feed of a few Facebook pages maintained by the owner of the site using the Facebook Graph API in order to use the content in the app. But instead of the feeds I get the following error:

```
To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.
```

I am requesting an URL of the format https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN] using an access token requested with a Client ID and a Client secret.

So I need to submit my app (which in my case must be the php backend, right?) for App Review in order to get the app to request the page feed correctly once again.

However the App Review application process is clearly meant for use cases where individual users sign in using their Facebook accounts and not for cases where a server side script authenticated with an access token grabs public data.

Because of this I can not submit a screencast nor can I describe where the permission is set. How can I get my app approved then?

Comment: _“using an access token requested with a Client ID and a Client secret”_ - that would be an app access token. Since you have admin access to the pages (at least by extension), you should be using a page access token - then this doesn’t fall under Page Public Content Access any more to begin with.

Comment: This might be a silly question but how do I get a page access token?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Did you ever pass the review, @Regicollis?

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful, regarding submitting apps with no interface.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way, the Facebook app review is a limit where they deny all small companies or groups of Developers. The Facebook APIs are for companies so if you have less than like 500,000 users, you have a high chance of not getting aprooved. I've tried for 2 months now, no progress. Its a loop, they tell me: dont use this, use that. I use it: this is not something you need, use the this(the one i already tried).

Update: You can try sending it again, as you will never be reviewed by the samd guy.

Comment: Seems to be true.